# How to disable the keyboardAvoidingView behaviour in TextInput

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a react native project made using react native cli. The problem is that the TextInput gets highlighted when the keyboard is visible/active & it squeezes the view and mess up the layout which reminded me of KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour. Even though I don't use `KeyboardAvoidingView` in this project because all text inputs are in the upper half of the screen so they won't get covered by the keyboard.

```
<TextInput
      style={styles.inputText}
      multiline={false}
      onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      onChangeText={numberInputHandler}
      value={enteredValue}/>

 inputText: {
      borderBottomColor: "white",
      borderBottomWidth: 2,
      width: "30%",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: Dimensions.get("window").height / 5,
      left: Dimensions.get("window").width / 5,
      color: "white",
      fontSize: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.03,
      fontFamily: "Lato-Regular"
      }
```

React Native Ver 0.61.5

Testing was done on an Android emulator and an Android physical device

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just Add                  
                                           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible|adjustPan"                        
                                                                                                                                 
into your ManifistFile in that activity where you want Keyboard do not change any behaviour

Answer (score 1):

As I can see  you are using absolute positioning where bottom uses **`Dimension api`** to get the height. The problem occurs due to this. Try giving static height rather then fetching from Dimension because when keyboard appears **visible window gets shrink** causing react to re-render because height changes.

```
position: "absolute",
bottom: Dimensions.get("window").height / 5,
```

Comment: same behaviour after I changed position to relative and commented bottom and left, the keyboard appearing always tries to squeeze the view and moves up the footer instead of hiding it, the same code behaves normally in an expo managed project but behaves this way in non-expo react native (this problem appeared when i copied my code from my initial expo project, and replaced the expo modules

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by Nikosssgr:

In AndroidManifest.xml

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" changed it to "adjustNothing"

Answer (score 0):

```
    justifyContent: "space-around"
```

Please add this to the `View` which contains the `TextInputs`. This solution works for me.